# Creating Separate Projects Or Using Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project that has to do with Suppliers who will have an admin interface to manage their inventory, buyers who will buy products showcased by suppliers and also have Admin. Which is better, Creating a separate project in thesame solution for each category role or creating Areas is the best

Comment: We need to know what you have tried.can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple Areas in the same web application will share the same authentication token. Meaning, after loggin in, a user can browse to the area and not need to login. With different projects you need to do a little bit of work to get this behavior (basically they all have to use the same authenticaion cookie and have the same key). If they don't share the same ticket then each project will have to make users login independently

Another thing to consider is url customization. With areas you can customize the url of the area controllers and the area itself. You can set up a custom route at the room website level to point to a controller in the areas folder. For example

Lets say you have http://www.yoursite.com/blog/article/index (article controller of the blog area), you can create a custom route off the root site so that http://www.yoursite.com/article points to the same place. This is much harder, if not impossible to do with sub projects since you are then depending on the folder structure.

However, a benefit to sub projects is that you can build them in isolation and deploy them without modifying the root site. This can be done with areas through the concept of portable areas.

Comment: Thanks for that piece @AmirNorouzpour. Does it have any effect on the size and load time of the project as whole

Comment: @AduwuJoseph In separate projects, the size and loading time should be greater